# Mostrando notificaciones en Firebase - Enviando una notificación a mi dispositivo

Tags: firebase, notificaciones, firebase-messaging

Estoy haciendo [un tutorial de codelabs y en el paso 11](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#10) tengo que mandar una petición http (Sección: "Send a notification to your device"):

```
POST /fcm/send HTTP/1.1
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY

{
  "notification": {
    "title": "New chat message!",
    "body": "There is a new message in FriendlyChat",
    "icon": "/images/profile_placeholder.png",
    "click_action": "http://localhost:5000"
  },
  "to":"YOUR_DEVICE_TOKEN"
}
```

La mando y falla algo.
Para mandarlo cojo el código anterio y pongo mi "server key" y mi "device token", quito los saltos de línea y lo pego en mi consola de windows. Obtengo el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Qué está fallando?**

Comment: Por lo que veo ahi dice Could not resolve host, creo que no haz ingresado el host :D

Comment: @Carlosgub pero el host no es fcm.googleapis.com?

Comment: Haz cambiado esto Authorization: key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY? o  sea YOUR_SERVER_KEY? haz tenido que cambiar eso

Comment: @Carlosgub ya ves que lo he cambiado, creo que lo estoy poniendo correctamente.

Comment: hola, creo que el host es el html de tu BD de firebase estoy casi seguro que no es fcm.googleapis.com